# Search data between date range AND add data between predefined date range

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fifo, stock

I am trying to build a searching application where people can see data according to date range inputed, but i want to add predefined date range too and add this result to the final output.

I have been searching the solution but i did not figure out how to do it. I think i must have been missed something. Would anyone please share the knowledge for me ?

FYI i am very new in coding.

Here is my form :

```php
    <table id="tbl_rekapbeli" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:900px;height:360px"
        url="get_lap_beli2.php" pagination="true" idField="id"
        title="Rekap Pembelian Berkala" toolbar="#tb"
        singleSelect="true" fitColumns="true" showFooter="true">
    <thead>
            <th field="no_po" width="50" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">No PO</th>
            <th field="tgl_po" width="50" editor="{type:'datebox',options:{required:true}}">Tgl PO</th>
            <th field="nama_outlet" width="50" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">Customer</th>
            <th field="kode_barang" width="50" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">Kode Barang</th>
            <th field="nama_barang" width="90" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">Nama Barang</th>
            <th field="qty_beli" width="50" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">Jumlah beli</th>
            <th field="harga_beli" width="50"  editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">Harga beli</th>
            <th field="jum_harga_beli" width="50" formatter="formatrp" editor="{type:'numberbox'}">Total</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div id="tb" style="padding:5px;height:auto">
    <div>
        Date From : <input id="date1" class="easyui-datebox" style="width:80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        To : <input id="date2" class="easyui-datebox" style="width:80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#" id="aaa" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-search">Cari</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script for function :

```js
var d1 = 0
var d2 = 0

$('#date1').datebox({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        d1 = date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate();
    }
})

$('#date2').datebox({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        d2 = date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate();
    }
})

$('#aaa').click(function () {
    $('#tbl_rekapbeli').datagrid('options').url = "get_lap_beli2.php?start_date=" + d1 + "&end_date=" + d2;
    $('#tbl_rekapbeli').datagrid('reload');
    //alert(“dari: ” + d1 + ” sampai: ” + d2);
})

function formatrp(val, row) {
    return number_format(val, '', ',', '.');
};

function number_format(num, dig, dec, sep) {
    x = new Array();
    s = (num < 0 ? "-" : "");
    num = Math.abs(num).toFixed(dig).split(".");
    r = num[0].split("").reverse();
    for (var i = 1; i <= r.length; i++) {
        x.unshift(r[i - 1]);
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i != r.length) x.unshift(sep);
    }
    return "Rp " + s + x.join("") + (num[1] ? dec + num[1] : "");
}
```

And for the action :

```php
$begin_date = '2015-07-01';
$start_date = $_REQUEST['start_date'];
$end_date = $_REQUEST['end_date'];

include '../../libs/conn.php';

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM beli WHERE tgl_po between '$begin_date' and '$start_date' AND tgl_po between '$start_date' and '$end_date'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
$result["total"] = $row[0];

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM beli WHERE tgl_po between '$begin_date' and '$start_date' AND tgl_po between '$start_date' and '$end_date'");

$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
array_push($items, $row);
}
$result["rows"] = $items;

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(jum_harga_beli) AS value_sum FROM beli WHERE tgl_po between '$begin_date' and '$start_date' AND tgl_po between '$start_date' and '$end_date'");
$rw = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$sum = $rw['value_sum'];

$result["footer"]=array(array("harga_beli" => "Total Pembelian",'jum_harga_beli' => $sum));

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: What result do you get when it runs? Any error output? Before anyone takes the step of running this code in their own sandbox it's always good etiquette to post your results of running the code. There could be configuration issues as well.

Comment: it shows only data from the date range selected, but i want the data from my predefined date range ( which is from 2015-07-01 to start date ) added to the final output too

Answer (score 0):

Your query has

```
  AND tgl_po between '$begin_date' and '$start_date'
  AND tgl_po between '$start_date' and '$end_date'
```

The way SQL works, you need `OR` rather than `AND` here.

```
  AND    (    tgl_po between '$begin_date' and '$start_date'
           OR tgl_po between '$start_date' and '$end_date')
```

If you mention `AND` in a where clause, it only accepts records matching *both* criteria. If you want it to match *either* criterion, you need `OR`.

You want rows matching either the first date range or the second. So you must specify `OR`, not `AND`. It's typical in SQL queries that `AND` narrows the selection and `OR` widens it.

Comment: i do need both data from two date ranges